# Why is the Fermi coupling $G_F$ is measured from muon decay?

Tags: standard-model, weak-interaction, electroweak

The decay rate of all weak processes, calculated from the $V$-$A$ theory will contain a factor of $G_F$, the Fermi coupling constant. However, $G_F$ is usually measured from $\mu^-$ decay which is in turn used to calculate the electroweak vacuum expectation value using $v=(\sqrt{2}G_F)^{-1/2}=246$ GeV.

Why is $\mu^-$ decay any special than any other weak decay for experimental determination of $G_F$ such as the nuclear $\beta$ decay?

Comment: Because it is cleaner than other processes.

Comment: Could you elaborate what do you mean by _cleaner_?

Comment: What other processes could you use? Those involving quarks are subject to the hadronic uncertainties. And the $\tau$ can decay both in muons and electrons, and muons are easier to identify, and , more importantly, to produce.

Comment: @marmot Okay. Agreed. I was thinking about $\beta$-decay, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muon decay has one major decay channel, $\mu^-\to e^-\bar{\nu}_e \nu_\mu$. (You can theoretically also create electron-positron pairs.) This means the decay rate is an easily calculated function of $G_F$, and inverting the function is difficult. With tau decay (for example), the decay could produce a muon or an electron, and in the former case the muon may or may not decay.